# Local Storage values are not storing and fetched in table format in my react js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am storing recentTrans data in local storage and trying to fetch the stored data after refreshing the page to historyVal but the entire data is storing in only **0th** index of the array as it is when I am spliting the data in history it printing in an uneven manner**[image: History Table]** . **How can store data in separate index of an array**.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import './App.css';

const Account = () => {
  // debugger;
    const [draw, setDraw] = useState();
    const [init, setInit] = useState();
    const [history, setHistory] = useState("none");
    const [status, setStatus]= useState("none");
    const [tableVal, setTableVal] = useState("none");
    const redirect = useHistory();  
    let hisArr = [];                        
    const getter = localStorage.getItem("IsLogin");

    let tbl = '';
    const table = <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Transaction Type</th>
                <th>Balance Amount</th>
                <th>Date & Time</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="recenttrans">
            {tbl}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    const table1 = <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Transaction Type</th>
                <th>Balance Amount</th>
                <th>Date & Time</th>
                <th>Amount</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="historyVal">
            {tbl}
        </tbody>
    </table>

     const Deposite = () => {
        setTableVal("block")
        const event = new Date().toLocaleString();
        const setter =parseInt( localStorage.getItem(getter))
        const store =   setter +parseInt(init);
        localStorage.setItem(getter, store);
        const table = document.getElementById('table');
        const row = table.insertRow(0);
        const table1 = row.insertCell(0);
        const table2 = row.insertCell(1);
        const table3 = row.insertCell(2);
        const table4 = row.insertCell(3);
        table1.innerHTML = "Deposit";
        table2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('depinput').value;
        table3.innerHTML = event;
        table4.innerHTML = store;
        document.getElementById("depinput").value = "";                        
    }  

    const Withdraw = () => {
        //debugger
        setTableVal("block")
        const event = new Date().toLocaleString();
        const getter = localStorage.getItem('IsLogin')
        const setter = localStorage.getItem(getter)
        const store1 = parseInt(setter) - parseInt(draw);
        localStorage.setItem(localStorage.getItem('IsLogin'), draw)
        localStorage.setItem(getter, store1);
        const table = document.getElementById('table');
        const row = table.insertRow(0);
        const table1 = row.insertCell(0);
        const table2 = row.insertCell(1);
        const table3 = row.insertCell(2);
        const table4 = row.insertCell(3);
        table1.innerHTML = "WithDraw";
        table2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('withinput').value;
        table3.innerHTML = event;
        table4.innerHTML = store1;
        if (store1 < 0) {
            table4.innerHTML = 0;
        }
        else {
            table4.innerHTML = 0;
           
            if (store1 < 0) {
                table4.innerHTML = 0
            }
            else {
                table4.innerHTML = store1;
            }
            document.getElementById("withinput").value = "";
        }                                                                  
    }                                                                     
    const RecentTrans = () => {
            setHistory("block");
            if (table !== "") {
                const table = document.getElementById('recenttrans');
                const transaction = document.getElementById('table').innerHTML;
                const myArr = [transaction.split("</tr>")];
                console.log(myArr)
                for (let i = 0; i < myArr[0].length; i++) {
                    const row = table.insertRow(i);
                    row.innerHTML = myArr[0][i]
                    localStorage.setItem("valhistory",myArr);
                }
            }  
    }
    const historyVal = () => {
            setStatus("block");
            if (table !== "") {
                const table = document.getElementById('historyVal');
                const hist = localStorage.getItem("valhistory");
                 hisArr = [hist.split("</tr>")];
                console.log(hisArr);
                for (let i = 0; i < hisArr[0].length; i++) {
                    const row = table.insertRow(i);
                    row.innerHTML = hisArr[i][0]
                }
            } 
    }
    const Signout = () => {
        redirect.push(`/`);
    
    }
    return (
    <div className="box">
        <div className="deposite">
            <fieldset className="fieldset">
            <legend>Deposite</legend>
                <input
                type="number"
                id="depinput" className="text"
                placeholder="Enter your money..."
                onChange={(e) => setInit(e.target.value)}
                        />
        </fieldset>
        </div>
                <button className="depositebtn" onClick={() => Deposite()}>Deposit</button>
                <br />
                <div className="withdraw">
                    <fieldset className="fieldset">
                        <legend>WithDraw</legend>
                        <input
                            type="number"
                            id="withinput" className="text"
                            placeholder="Enter your money..."
                            onChange={(e) => setDraw(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <button className="withdrawbtn" onClick={() => Withdraw()}>WithDraw</button>
                <div className="tab" style={{display:tableVal}}>
                    <table border="">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Transaction Type</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                                <th>Date & Time</th>
                                <th>Balance Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="table">
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button className="recent" onClick={() => RecentTrans()}>Recent Transaction</button>
                    {history ?
                        <div className="tbl" style={{display:history}}>{table}</div>
                        : console.log("Hello")}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button className="recent" onClick={() => historyVal()}>History</button>
                        <div className="tbl" style={{display:status}}>{table1}</div> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button className="signout" onClick={() => Signout()}>Sign Out</button>
                </div>
    </div>
        )
}
    export default Account
```

As per the bellow snap shots the same format is not reflecting in history as transaction table
[Transaction Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrDPh.png)

[image: History Table]

Comment: `hisArr = [hist.split("</tr>")];` you put the array resulting from the split operation inside another array, thereby making it the 0th element.  Try removing the square brackets from this line.

Comment: I think my question is not asked correctly. Please suggest me any solution or any changes to my question. Thankyou

Comment: You should probably use something like [`useLocalStorage`](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) to manage your local storage.

Comment: Ok can you suggest any solution please.

Comment: Thank you  I will try this solution.

Comment: Hi James, When i remove the square brackets I am getting infinite loop and when i try use if condition and break I am getting the values printed  in same uneven format.

Comment: Hi Andy, Can we pass array's through useLocalStorage . Can you please share me any examples. Thank you

Comment: Yes you would need to change some other code to support the different structure, like don't loop through hist[0] any more.  Please give it a try to fix the associated errors, I suggest the root of the problem and leave you to repair it.